# Delayed_job not working in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm simply trying to get a function to run at a specific time, but I'm not having much luck. Let me just run through the basics of what I've done

```
#Gemfile

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

---

```
#config/application.rb

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
  end
end
```

---

```
#Ran from command line

[06.07.2017/15:38:02] user@ubuntu $ rails g delayed_job:active_record
Running via Spring preloader in process 72879
   identical  bin/delayed_job
       chmod  bin/delayed_job
      create  db/migrate/20170607203821_create_delayed_jobs.rb
[06.07.2017/15:38:21] user@ubuntu $ rake db:migrate
== 20170607203821 CreateDelayedJobs: migrating ================================
-- create_table(:delayed_jobs, {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0088s
-- add_index(:delayed_jobs, [:priority, :run_at], {:name=>"delayed_jobs_priority"})
   -> 0.0051s
== 20170607203821 CreateDelayedJobs: migrated (0.0142s) =======================
```

So I basically have a button on my view that calls `post_now`, which then calls a function within a custom model that I have. Here's an example of what I have:

```
#posts_controller.rb
  def post_now
    set_post
    submit_post = SchedulePost.delay(run_at: 1.minute.from_now).schedule_post(@post)
    redirect_to posts_path, flash: {success: submit_post[1] }
  end
```

and then here's the SchedulePost class, which is simply writing a text file (for now)

```
#models/schedule_post.rb
class SchedulePost < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.schedule_post(post)
        command = "touch #{Rails.root}/public/test.txt"
        system(command)
        return
    end
end
```

So what I'm expecting to happen is that when post_now is called, it's supposed to run the schedule_post function 1 minute from now, which is simply supposed to write a text file. If I remove the `.delay(run_at: 1.minute.from_now)` block and just leave `schedule_post` there, then it works fine. So I'm definitely doing something wrong here with the delay function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the delayed_job worker to perform delayed tasks...in your terminal from app root directory do

```
rake jobs:work
```

Comment: Gotcha. How can I background this? Would I just run `rake jobs:work &` to let this run in the background?

Comment: That's what is your background woker. It is seperate and independent from the main worker(server). Just run the command and it will keep executing tasks as and when spawned..

Comment: Ok. I just wanted to have one less terminal opened while this was going, but I get what you're saying. Thanks man!